# Advantage of using stride in swift

Tags: swift, stride

Can you explain the advantage of stride in Swift and its **peculiar** use?

*e.g.*:

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 1) {
    print(i)  // prints from 0 to 9
}
```

Instead of this we can use `for` loop also.

Comment: That is a `for` loop. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Instead of stride we can also use          for i in 0...10{ print (i) }

Comment: But `stride` has the `by` parameter.

Comment: There is no advantage if you want to increase the iterator by 1.

Comment: That is we can increment value of 2 in a single step.Ok,

Comment: You can use negative value also

Comment: so, if we want to increment the iterator more than 1, its not possible in for i in 0...10{print(i)}.  But by using stride its possible.

Comment: @Akash Exactly, you can't do that with the `...` operator.

Comment: Ok, thankyou everyone

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to be asking about the benefits of `stride` over a basic `for` loop with a range such as `1..<10`.

`stride` supports incrementing by values other than 1.

```
// count by 3
for x in stride(from: 3, to: 30, by: 3) {
}

// Backwards
for n in stride(from: 20, to: 0, by: -4) {
}
```

`stride` works with non-integer values.

```
for r in stride(from: 3.14, to: 234.14234, by: 5.6345) {
}
```